# Light led using raspberryPi using php and python scripts

Tags: php, python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am trying to light a led using raspberryPi using php and python.The contents of php file is :

```
<?php 
$output = shell_exec('python /script/test.py'); 
echo $output;
?>
```

test.py file contains the code :

```
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
 GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
 GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT) 
 GPIO.output(7,True)
```

When I open the php script in localhost,the light is not on.Dont know whether this method is practical.How to switch on led using php and python?

Comment: quick question : why do you need php for this? flask (for example) is a small python framework for web apps that would allow you to do all that without having php call an external program

Comment: also: did you try to just run the python script? called from a command line? did it work?

Comment: also: are you sure you turn on the proper gpio pin ?

Comment: I am more comfortable with php.So thought of implementing this in php

Comment: apparently most of your code is in python (unless you'll have a gui in html?) (sorry about the off topic, though).